# All my fonts show up in monospace in Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts

All of a sudden, with no intervention from me, Chrome keeps displaying monospace fonts on many different websites. When I go to set the fonts in Chrome settings, the rendered text does not reflect the font selection I have made. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and Chromium 87.0.4280.88.

[image: Monospace SuperUser]
[image: Monospace]

Comment: Changing from Chromium to Google Chrome fixes it.